# Given $\mathbb{A}$ a family of sets show that for every set D $(\bigcap \mathcal{A}) \cup D=\bigcap\{A \cup D: A \in \mathcal{A}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$(\bigcap \mathcal{A}) \cup D=\bigcap\{A \cup D: A \in \mathcal{A}\}$

I Did For

$.$ if $x \in\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i}\right) \cup D,$ then $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i}$ or $x \in D .$ Let $i_{0} \in I$ be arbitrary. Then $A_{i_{0}} \supseteq \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i},$ so $x \in A_{i_{0}}$ or $x \in D,$ and therefoer $x \in A_{i_{0}} \cup D .$ since this holds for each $i_{0} \in I$ $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I}\left(A_{i} \cup D\right) .$ Conversely, if $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I}\left(A_{i} \cup D\right),$ then $x \in A_{i} \cup D$ for each $i \in I .$ If $x \in D$
then certainly $x \in\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i}\right) \cup D .$ If $x \notin D,$ then we must have $x \in A_{i}$ for each $i \in I,$ in which case $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i} \subseteq\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i}\right) \cup D$

is right?

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me

Comment: Three people agree, so probably it's right.

Comment: Yes, it’s fine.